# entity framework code first inverse property generated column name

Tags: ef-code-first

For simple FK I could change the generated column name by using

```
    [ForeignKey("CustomList1")]
    public int? CustomList1ID { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomList CustomList1 { get; set; }
```

But for inverseProperty (as I have multiple customList, how to control the generated column name for the database?

```
    [InverseProperty("CustomList1")]
    public virtual List<Customer> CustomerCustomList1 { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ForeignKey("CustomList1")] Does not  change the generated column name.

1. If placed on the navigation property, it specifies the name of the field used to retreive the correct entity.
2. If placed on the field property, it specifies the associated navigation property that use this field as FK.

If you want to change the column name generated, you should use :
[Column("YOU_COLUMN_NAME")].

Comment: I know ForeignKey("CustomList1") does not change column name but the next line explicitly add a FK key will get me the name i needed.

I also know column("myname") will do for simple FK, but for InverseProperty it does not seems to work.